# .netCore App v1.0.1 instant error at debug 'System.IO.FileStream'

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, .net-core

I am developing a .net core app `v1.0.1`.
I am hashing passwords to safe it to a database.
To do this I use the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.KeyDerivation` v1.1.2.

now when I try to debug my application I get an instant error:

> Ein Ausnahmefehler des Typs "System.TypeLoadException" ist in Unbekanntes Modul. aufgetreten.
>
> Zusätzliche Informationen: Could not load type 'System.IO.Directory' from assembly 'System.IO.FileSystem, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

For me it seems like there is an incompatibility between versions.

my `project.json` looks like this:

```
{
  

> "dependencies": {
>     "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
>       "version": "1.0.1",
>       "type": "platform"
>     },
>     "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.0",
>     "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
>     "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.1",
>     "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
>     "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
>     "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
>     "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
>     "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
>     "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
>     "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
>     "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
>     "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
>     "MySql.Data": "6.10.1-beta",
>     "System.Data.Common": "4.3.0",
>     "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core": "2.2.1",
>     "System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms": "4.3.0",
>     "JWT": "2.4.2",
>     "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.KeyDerivation": "1.1.2"   },
>     "tools": {
>       "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
>     },   "frameworks": {
>     "netcoreapp1.0": {
>       "imports": [
>         "dotnet5.6",
>         "net46",
>         "net451",
>         "portable-net45+win8"
>       ]
>     }   },
>     "buildOptions": {
>       "emitEntryPoint": true,
>       "preserveCompilationContext": true
>     },
>     "runtimeOptions": {
>       "configProperties": {
>         "System.GC.Server": true
>       }
>     },
>     "publishOptions": {
>       "include": [
>         "wwwroot",
>         "**/*.cshtml",
>         "appsettings.json",
>         "web.config"
>       ]
>     },
>     "scripts": {
>       "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
>     }   }
```

Which versions do I have to use or what do I have to add to get my project running?